# Checking date chronology in excel 2016 using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

Got two columns of data in excel, all data entries are dates:

- First column J6 through J100
- Second column K6 through K100

I need to make sure that no date in the second column (K) ever precedes the dates in the first column (J). I don't think I can use conditional formatting for this.

Using VBA, how would I check each pair of dates and then cause a cell in column K to turn RED if that date precedes the corresponding date in J?

Thanks for all the help! I included a picture below if that helps. I don't think it matters if the K values are blank because I'll want to know if those are blank and the code would read those just like any other date that turns red.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: So to be clear, if the cell is blank, you don't  want to color code it, just leave it as is?

Comment: Why can't you use conditional formatting for this? How about a rule with the formula `=K2<=J2`. Bonus - it also works with blank cells.

Comment: I could do conditional formatting line by line but this loops through both columns at one time, seems much more efficient, isn't it?

Comment: You don't need to conditional format line by line - select K6:K100 and enter your conditional formatting all at once.

Comment: I tried that but it said that I couldn't conditional format like that.....if you could spell it out I'd appreciate it because I definitely thought I'd be able to, but I couldn't get it to work

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, this will do the trick for preceding dates or if they are blank.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Color()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '---Name it whatever the sheet name is
Dim x As Integer

For x = 6 To 100
    If ws.Cells(x, 11).Value2 <= ws.Cells(x, 10).Value2 Then
        ws.Cells(x, 11).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) '---colors the cell red
    ElseIf ws.Cells(x, 11).Value2 = "" Then
        ws.Cells(x, 11).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) '---If you want to color the blank ones as well
    End If
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: This was a homerun, thanks.  For some reason I had to add another else if to make sure that the proper dates stayed white, but this was great, thanks

Comment: @throwbackdev37 No problem, don't forget to mark this as the correct answer and upvote my answer.

Comment: Just checked it off.....i'm such a noob that they won't take my upvotes yet

Comment: @throwbackdev37 - That's alright, thanks for the correct answer! good luck with your project.  This site has been extremely helpful for me!

Comment: @BigBen - Good catch, thanks I was typing it up fast and didn't catch it.  It is not fixed

Comment: Well I had to switch a couple of things on here, you're right it was supposed to be <= instead of >=, i just switched the 11 to 10 and vice versa instead of switching the operator

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your sheet is sheet1 if not just change the name in Worksheets("")

```
Sub CompareDates()
     Dim Counter As Integer
     Dim myDate As Date
     Dim myDateCompare As Date

 For Counter = 1 To 100
 myDate = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 10).Value 'Refers to Column J
 myDateCompare = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 11).Value 'Refers to Column K
 If myDate > myDateCompare Then Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Counter, 11).Interior.ColorIndex = 46
 Next Counter
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a ton.  Currently getting a run time error: 9 with that but I'm going to look more into it!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just to show that you can do this using conditional formatting...

1. Select the range "K6:K100".
2. Under Conditional Formatting, add a "New Rule".
3. Use a formula to determine which cells to format:
4. Enter `=K6<=J6` as your formula and set the format to Red Fill.

*Before Conditional Formatting*
[image]

*After Conditional Formatting*

[image]

Comment: I've tried that out but it's not returning any cells red.

Comment: Hmm I meant `=K6<=J6` as the formula, not `=K2...`. Edited. If you still can't replicate I'll add pictures.

Comment: Yep you're right.  I think there may be issues with applying the conditional formatting on the excel worksheet I'm downloading for some reason, but you're right it can be done that way.  Thanks